# Excel - removing any data found within ( ) within a cell while separating remaining data into aadditional columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to take the data that is presently in a given cell such as:

[image]

and have it yield the following:

[image]

Is there an automated way to do this?

TYIA

I've googled and tried to find a way and I don't quite know the proper search terms to find what I'm looking for if it's possible.

Comment: Please don't post images of text. Put the text in your post instead.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
=TEXTBEFORE(TEXTSPLIT(A1,"; ")," (")
```

Here is the output:
[image: output]